# In R, how do I automatically annotate every figure saved?

Tags: r, pdf, graph, annotations

Figures and graphs that I save in my R session are usually for my documentation, and I would like to annotate them with working directory, file name and date. Since I need to hardcopy my documentation (don't ask), that would make my life easier. I was thinking that I could modify the pdf's before printing, but I actually prefer to have the figures stamped directly in R.

Since most of the time I generate graphics with `dev.copy2pdf()`, I concocted the following little function:

```
# annotate PDF copy of the graph produced
copyan <- function( file= "tmp.pdf", cex= 0.75 ) {

  oldpar <- par( mar= c( 0, 0, 0, 0 ), usr= c( 0, 1, 0, 1 ) )
  on.exit( par( oldpar ) )

  par( new= TRUE )
  plot.new()

  # ann is the annotation stamp:
  # current working directory,
  # file name, date and time.
  ann <- paste( getwd(), file, Sys.time(), sep= ", " )
  strh <- strheight( ann, cex= cex )
  strw <- strwidth(  ann, cex= cex )

  # put text in the lower bottom corner,
  # just at the very margin of the plot
  usr1 <- par( "usr" )
  text( usr1[1] + strw/2, usr1[3] + strh/2, ann, cex= cex )

  dev.copy2pdf( file= file )
}
```

Though it works reasonably well with the plots I am usually generating, maybe there is already a better solution OOB? Or, maybe, the above script can be improved?

Comment: If you're getting the annotation you want in the location on the plots you intend, why change anything? :-) .  Perhaps you could turn it into a function, just to make it easier to loop over N graphs, etc.

Comment: Well, I did (it is a part of my "handy little tools that I need everyday" package which I always install wherever I work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your own function that wraps `dev.copy2pdf` is a good idea, I think that you are going about it the long way.  Look at the functions `mtext` and `title` for different ways of placing text in the margins.  If those don't quite do what you want then use `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` with `text` after setting `par(xpd=NA)`.  In all cases you may want to use the `adj` argument to specify adjustment rather than computing string width and height and moving values by half of that.

Answer (score 1):

For grid graphics I've used the following,

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(1, 1)

stamp <- paste("Data: Monday 24 June 2013", 
               strftime(Sys.time(), "Plotted: %A %d %B %Y @%H:%M"), 
               sep="\n")

grid.arrange(p, sub=textGrob(stamp, gp=gpar(cex=0.8, col="grey"), 
                             hjust=1, vjust=0, x=1))
```

[image]